# Remove recyclerview item via swiping

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have problem with image while swiping recyclerview item, like on picture. Have anyone idea how can I hide this trash under the swiping element? This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    Bitmap icon;
    if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){
        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
        float width = height / 3;

        if(dX < 0){
            p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
            RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
            c.drawRect(background,p);
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24dp);
            icon = drawableToBitmap(d);
            RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
            if(dX < 0){
                c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
            }
        }
    }
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using any library to swipe? @forfiter

Comment: No i dont use any library to this

Answer (score 0):

```
activity_main.xml
--------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.learn2crack.recyclerswipeview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


------------------------------
row_layout.xml

-------------


row_layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_country"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
---------------------------

dialog_layout.xml
----------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

---------------------------------

DataAdapter.java
--------------------------------
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private ArrayList countries;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countries.size();
    }

    public void addItem(String country) {
        countries.add(country);
        notifyItemInserted(countries.size());
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        countries.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, countries.size());
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_country;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_country = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
        }
    }
}

---------------------------------------


MainActivity.java
---------------------
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ArrayList countries =  new ArrayList<>();
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
    private EditText et_country;
    private int edit_position;
    private View view;
    private boolean add = false;
    private Paint p = new Paint();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
        initDialog();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new DataAdapter(countries);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        countries.add("Australia");
        countries.add("India");
        countries.add("United States of America");
        countries.add("Germany");
        countries.add("Russia");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        initSwipe();

    }
    private void initSwipe(){
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                    adapter.removeItem(position);
                } else {
                    removeView();
                    edit_position = position;
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Edit Country");
                    et_country.setText(countries.get(position));
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

                Bitmap icon;
                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

                    View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                    float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                    float width = height / 3;

                    if(dX > 0){
                        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#388E3C"));
                        RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX,(float) itemView.getBottom());
                        c.drawRect(background,p);
                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_edit_white);
                        RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getLeft()+ 2*width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                        c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                    } else {
                        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                        RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                        c.drawRect(background,p);
                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_delete_white);
                        RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                        c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                    }
                }
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
    private void removeView(){
        if(view.getParent()!=null) {
            ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
        }
    }
    private void initDialog(){
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null);
        alertDialog.setView(view);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(add){
                    add =false;
                    adapter.addItem(et_country.getText().toString());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    countries.set(edit_position,et_country.getText().toString());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
        et_country = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_country);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.fab:
                removeView();
                add = true;
                alertDialog.setTitle("Add Country");
                et_country.setText("");
                alertDialog.show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between mine and your function onChildDraw()?